# How to create a download function where file changes depending on which object it's under

Tags: javascript, html, json, download, blob

I am now working on download buttons for my site, but this download function won't work correctly when I add a template literal to the download link:

```js
const logoData = [

  {
    name: "Arizona Cardinals",
    png: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/moose1645/SLV/master/logos/NFL/png/500/ARI.png",
  },
  {
    name: "Atlanta Falcons",
    png: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/moose1645/SLV/master/logos/NFL/png/500/ATL.png",
  }

];


function logoTemplate(logo) {

  return `
  <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">${logo.name}</h5>
    <a type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="downloadIt()" href="#">Download PNG</a>
  </div>
</div>
`

}


function downloadIt() {
  function forceDownload(blob, filename) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.download = filename;
    a.href = blob;

    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    a.remove();
  }

  function downloadResource(url, filename) {
    if (!filename) filename = url.split('\\').pop().split('/').pop();
    fetch(url, {
        headers: new Headers({
          'Origin': location.origin
        }),
        mode: 'cors'
      })
      .then(response => response.blob())
      .then(blob => {
        let blobUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        forceDownload(blobUrl, filename);
      })
      .catch(e => console.error(e));
  }

  downloadResource(`${logo.png}`);
}


document.getElementById("library").innerHTML = `
<div class="container">
${logoData.map(logoTemplate).join('')}
</div>
`
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="library">
</div>
```

The download function works when I hard code it something like: `downloadResource('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/moose1645/SLV/master/logos/NFL/png/500/ARI.png')`
 but I want the file to change depending on the object it's under.

I want the first button to download this file: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/moose1645/SLV/master/logos/NFL/png/500/ARI.png

and I want the second button to download this file: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/moose1645/SLV/master/logos/NFL/png/500/ATL.png

Basically, I just want each object to have a button that on click automatically downloads the `png` value from this data

```js
  const logoData = [

  {
    name: "Arizona Cardinals",
    png: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/moose1645/SLV/master/logos/NFL/png/500/ARI.png",
  },
  {
    name: "Atlanta Falcons",
    png: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/moose1645/SLV/master/logos/NFL/png/500/ATL.png",
  }

];
```

.

Instead, I get error. Any advice would be extremely appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the problem with string concatenation?

Comment: I want the first button to download this file: `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/moose1645/SLV/master/logos/NFL/png/500/ARI.png`
and the second button to download this file: `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/moose1645/SLV/master/logos/NFL/png/500/ATL.png`
basically, I want each item (${logo}) to have a button that downloads its image (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/moose1645/SLV/master/${logo.pngFile})

Comment: Sorry that last bit wasn't supposed to link somewhere.